# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. while installing SQL Server in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sql-server, linux, database, ubuntu

I'm installing SQL Server on Linux Ubuntu 18.04, according to the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15, however when executing the first command

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

I get the following error

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I've done several researches about the error, installed ca-certificates, installed all the gpg packages but I still can't solve the problem, can someone direct me to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the internet connection configuration, in my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file, the network mask was wrong

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I believe 99.99% of it's a connection issue. You might be connecting through a firewall or VPN. I have the same issue when I only connect through the company network. I tried the same command on a machine at my house, and it's working just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32030856)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add "--no-check-certificate" to the command:

`wget --no-check-certificate -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

If you want to see what is going on, you can use verbose command instead of quiet before adding "--no-check-certificate" option. e.g.

`wget -vO - https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

This will tell you to use "--no-check-certificate" if you are behind proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The command works fine for me.  In all likelihood there is a firewall or proxy server silently blocking and/or rewriting the web page.

Do this:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
```

In all likelihood it will print out something that tells you what is intercepting the traffic and preventing you from getting the real key.  Once you figure out what's blocking the traffic, you'll have to figure out how to get it to stop.

Comment: I ran the `wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc ` command and didn't get any messages

Comment: Then that’s a problem... it should have shown you the GPG key in text format. Things to check: are you on a corporate network that requires a proxy. Do you have an active internet connection. Is a firewall enabled that’s blocking web access.  Can you hit the same URL using a web browser?

Comment: What protocols and ports need to be open for this command?